# Find actual opened logfile with JDK Logging

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I saw [Java Logging - where is my log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457976/java-logging-where-is-my-log-file), but in my case I would like to find out in my Java application which logfile the `FileHandler` actually opened, i.e. if I start multiple processes and have a pattern set as

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=MyApp.%g.%u.log
```

Then the `%g` and `%u` will be replaced with numbers depending on how many processes are running.

I can iterate over all logging Handlers and find the File-based one. But as far as I see there is no method in `FileHandler` to get the currently opened file.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Related: [JDK-4798814 getFiles() needed for java.util.logging.FileHandler](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4798814).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can break the `private` protection of the field using reflection. See this question: [How do I read a private field in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java)

The next option is to override the class and write your own handler which exposes this field.

The last option is to use a different logging framework like logback or log4j2. Writing your own appender for them would be more simple than for JUL.

Comment: I actually used a combination of these, an extended FileHandler which actually needs to use the "lockName" as the original filename is not even available as member any more, so I ended up doing:

 Field f = FileHandler.class.getDeclaredField("lockFileName");
 f.setAccessible(true);
 return StringUtils.removeEnd((String) f.get(this), ".lck");

Comment: I just posted a similar question, but I'm looking for a Java 9 solution that doesn't require reflection. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697915/find-log-file-name-at-run-time-with-java-9-jdk-logging