# Find log file name at run time with Java 9 JDK Logging

Tags: java, reflection, java-9

I have the same question as [Find actual opened logfile with JDK Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707522/find-actual-opened-logfile-with-jdk-logging), except that I want to use an API that's supported by Java 9.

In Java 8, I currently use nearly the same reflection hack as described in the answer to that question except that I look at the actual log file name instead of parsing the lockFileName.

Here's my code:

```
private static String logFileName = null;

public static String getLogFileName() {
    // determined on demand and cached so we only need to do all of this the first time.
    if (logFileName == null) {
        for (Handler handler : Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers()) {
            if (handler.getClass().isAssignableFrom(FileHandler.class)) {
                FileHandler fileHandler = (FileHandler) handler;
                try {
                    // FileHandler.files has private access, 
                    // so I'm going to resort to reflection to get the file name.
                    Field privateFilesField = fileHandler.getClass().getDeclaredField("files");
                    privateFilesField.setAccessible(true); // allow access to this private field
                    File[] files = (File[]) privateFilesField.get(fileHandler);
                    logFileName = files[0].getCanonicalPath();
                    break;
                } catch (NullPointerException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | IOException ex) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to determine log file name.", ex);
                }
            }
        }
        if (logFileName == null) {
            logFileName = "your home directory"; // just be sure it's not null
            logger.warning("Unable to identify log file name.");
        }
    }
    return logFileName;
}
```

The reflection hack works fine in both Java 8 & 9, but in Java 9, it generates the following warning which I'd prefer to fix rather than ignore with the --illegal-access=permit flag.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.foo.MyApp (file:/C:/Users/me/Documents/foo/build/classes/java/main/) to field java.util.logging.FileHandler.files
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.foo.MyApp
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: FileHandler is not easily subclassed to get to the files field, hence the reflection.  Note for Java 9 this is just a warning, so you can do that for now.

Answer (score 0):

If a linux-specific solution is good enough you can try resolving the pseudo-symlinks in `/proc/self/fd/`, one of them should be the currently open logfile, matching the logging file pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this:

1. File a change request with the JDK to allow access to the field (at least make it `protected` so you can read it in a subclass).
2. Parse the properties file used to configure the appender. You will have to copy some of the logic out of the Java 9 code but chances are that this code won't change for a long time (backwards compatibility).
3. Copy a lot of code out of the logging API so you can write your own `FileHandler` which allows access to the field. While at it, you could also add code to iterate over all appenders.
4. Use a different logging framework.